# Give focus to textBox on key press

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

I want to give a textbox focus when the user starts typing anywhere in my app.

My page inherits from LayoutAwarePage.

Can this be achieved ?

Edit:
I got this code:

```
    // In constructor
    Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += CoreWindow_KeyDown;

    // Somewhere else in class
    void CoreWindow_KeyDown(Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow sender, Windows.UI.Core.KeyEventArgs args)
    {
        this.setSearchboxFocus((int)args.VirtualKey);
    }

    private void setSearchboxFocus(int keyCode)
    {
        if (keyCode == 38)
            return;

        if (keyCode == 40)
            return;

        if (this.searchBox.FocusState == Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Unfocused)
        {
            this.searchBox.Text = "";
            this.searchBox.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Keyboard);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone reading this thread in the future, it is because of the webview.  I asked a similar question on the [msdn forum here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bf4c22cd-77ac-40b1-8585-5799bcacf9d9/how-can-i-get-keyboard-events-if-a-webview-has-focus?forum=winappswithcsharp). As of Windows 8.1, the webview is implemented as a separate window and completely steals all keyboard input when it has focus without passing any of it up to the controlling application.  If you are able to change the HTML in the website being called it may be possible to use javascript listeners to pass events between the application and webview, but I did not test this myself.  Unfortunately there does not seem to be any other workaround at this time.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the KeyDown/KeyUp event for the whole page by subscribing to these events

```
Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown += CoreWindow_KeyDown;
Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyUp += CoreWindow_KeyUp
```

Comment: I tried this with mixed results. Cant it be because i have a webview on the page as well?

Comment: What do you mean by mixed results ?

Comment: When i press outside the webview i start recieving the events. If i press something inside the webview i get no events. Now i just need the webview to send keyDown events. (I have tried registering for the keyDown event on the webview itselfs)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (!textBox1.Focused)
    {
        textBox1.Focus();
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to find any ProcessCmdKey to override from Page.

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
 textBox1.Focus();//sets focus to textBox1 when user presses a key on form
}
```

Comment: Well. I dont have a form ? I got a Page.

Answer (score 0):

How about, on the Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page:

```
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Keyboard);
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
```

Comment: I tried this with mixed results. Can it be because i have a webview on the page as well?